# I am encountering a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: spring-boot

`I am encountering a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError with the message "javax/ws/rs/core/Configuration" when migrating Spring Boot application from version 2.7 to 3.1

Comment: Spring Boot 3 is JakartaEE not JavaEE. If you upgrade to Spring Boot 3.x you have to use all JakartaEE compatible libraries and frameworks. The one you use isn't suitable for JakartaEE (or at least the version you are using and thus you need to upgrade that as well).

Answer (score 0):

Add the following dependency to your class path

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: still same error. Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.core.Configuration

Comment: @VadirajHebbar updated my answer. could you check if it works?

Comment: no it not worked